# Flutter Bloc - How to correctly use parameters in bloc

Tags: flutter, dart, stream, bloc, clean-architecture

I'm new with the flutter bloc architecture.
I have an AuthBloc that emit a Stream of User.

Now, in some my lower level blocs, I need to access the id of the User, such as in a UserProfile Bloc.
I cannot decide which is the best approach for that.

For Instance I could:

- Subscribe to the user Stream of the bloc and fire a newUserEvent every time the user change. This could work well, but since I then have to subscribe to a stream of user profile edits from the repository the logic seems clunky.
- The second approach I thought of was of instantiating the bloc by passing the UserId as a parameter when I create it in the blocProvider of that route, for exemple passing it as a route parameter.

```
    class UserBloc extends Bloc<UserEvent, UserState> {
      final String userId;
      final UserRepository _userRepository;
      StreamSubscription? _userDetailsSubscription;
    
      UserBloc(this.userId, this._userRepository) : super(UserState.loading()) {
        _userRepository.getUserDetails(userId).listen((userDetails) {
            add(UserDetailsChanged(userDetails));
          })
            ..onError(
```

- Finally I could also assume the user is already authenticated when instanciating UserBloc and I could just retrieve from the userRepository the last value of the authRepository user stream. I like probably this approach best, but the drawback is that my streamSubscription of userDetails become a Future :

```
class UserBloc extends Bloc<UserEvent, UserState> {
     final UserRepository _userRepository;
     StreamSubscription? _userDetailsSubscription;

     UserBloc(this._userRepository) : super(UserState.loading()) {
       _userRepository.getUserDetails().then((stream) {
         _userDetailsSubscription = stream.listen((userDetails) {
           add(UserDetailsChanged(userDetails));
         })
           ..onError(
```

I tried to find the reccomended way to approach this but I couldn't find any firm opinion.

Answer (score 0):

The second option sounds the simplest, but the first one sounds like the correct one.

What you described in the first option is just simple BLoC-to-BLoC communication and I do not see the "clunkiness" in this solution. You can find some examples in bloc library Github repository, e.g.: https://github.com/felangel/bloc/blob/master/examples/flutter_todos/lib/blocs/filtered_todos/filtered_todos_bloc.dart.

I do not think there is an "official" solution, you just need to choose the one that fits to your problem.